# MPAndroidChart mMonths not support Utf-8

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use this Component for android studio "MPAndroidChart"=>https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

but in ِdemobase when I change for example Sep to "قمری"

in app shows me ***** and not show "قمری"

What should I do?

Comment: You should probably open a new issue at the github repository

Comment: Do you know what database is being used? It is likely the Android SQLite database (or table / column definition) may not be using UTF-8. M4rtini's suggestion seems the best route.